# C# Session Variables

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to pass multiple session variables to multiple asp pages. However, only the last ImageID and Extention values pass into the asp pages. I need to op

```
    int key = Convert.ToInt32(StockSummary.SelectedRow.Cells[6].Text);
    int index = 1;
    try
    {

        transportFbConn.Open();

        if (transportFbConn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            transportFbConn.Open();
        }
        var sqlquerry = String.Format("select image_key,File_EXT from IMAGE_LIST where SOURCE_PK = {0}", key);
        transportFbCommand = new FbCommand(sqlquerry, transportFbConn);
        transportFbReader = transportFbCommand.ExecuteReader();
        if (transportFbReader.HasRows)
        {
            while (transportFbReader.Read())
            {
                ImageID = transportFbReader.GetString(0);
                extention = transportFbReader.GetString(1);
                //Open PDF:
                if (ImageID != "")
                {
                    Session.Add("IMGID", ImageID);
                    Session.Add("Ext", extention);
                    Response.Write(string.Format("<script>window.open('{0}','_blank');</script>", "Trace"+index+".aspx"));
                }
                else
                {
                    this.ErrorLabel.Text = "No Trace Information found for Part Number : " + this.TextTextBox.Text;
                }
                index++;
            }
        }
```

I tried the arraylist but I get the object null reference:

```
 int key = Convert.ToInt32(StockSummary.SelectedRow.Cells[6].Text);
        int index = 1;
        int arrayindex = 0;
        ArrayList imageid = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList extention = new ArrayList();
        try
        {

            transportFbConn.Open();

            if (transportFbConn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                transportFbConn.Open();
            }
            var sqlquerry = String.Format("select image_key,File_EXT from IMAGE_LIST where SOURCE_PK = {0}", key);
            transportFbCommand = new FbCommand(sqlquerry, transportFbConn);
            transportFbReader = transportFbCommand.ExecuteReader();
            if (transportFbReader.HasRows)
            {
                while (transportFbReader.Read())
                {
                    imageid.Insert(arrayindex, transportFbReader.GetString(0));
                    extention.Insert(arrayindex, transportFbReader.GetString(1));
                    //Open PDF:
                    if (ImageID[arrayindex].ToString() != "")
                    {
                        Session.Add("IMGID", ImageID[arrayindex]);
                        Session.Add("Ext", extention[arrayindex]);
                        Response.Write(string.Format("<script>window.open('{0}','_blank');</script>", "Trace"+index+".aspx"));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.ErrorLabel.Text = "No Trace Information found for Part Number : " + this.TextTextBox.Text;
                    }
                    index++;
                    arrayindex++;
                }
            }
```

Comment: The session is a `key` `value` store. Are you trying to store more than one value under the same key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's better to create an array that store all keys, values in a temp variable then to store it on the session.
because using the same key will overwrite the value

```
ArrayList ar_IMGID = new ArrayList();
ArrayList ar_Ext = new ArrayList();

while (transportFbReader.Read())
            {
                ImageID = transportFbReader.GetString(0);
                extention = transportFbReader.GetString(1);
                //Open PDF:
                if (ImageID != "")
                {

                    ar_IMGID.Add(ImageID);
                    ar_Ext.Add(extention);
                 }
             }
Session.Add("IMGID", ar_ImageID);
Session.Add("Ext", ar_Ext);
```

Comment: I tried the arraylist but I get the "Object null reference":

Comment: may be you have an error in code.. please send me the code

Comment: I get the error on line:  if (ImageID[arrayindex].ToString() != "")

Comment: No the code is not correct..
you should insert the value to the array list only if it's not null
like the code in my answer
if it's not clear I can update ur code

Comment: or simply add this  if (ImageID[arrayindex] != null && ImageID[arrayindex].ToString() != "")

Comment: by the way you should add the array to the session outside the loop

Comment: where should I include the line to open the new web page: Response.Write(string.Format("<script>window.open('{0}','_blank');</script>", "Trace"+index+".aspx"));

Comment: I need to open a new webpage for each row returned in the loop( for each imageid and extention)

Comment: You don't need to use sessions
you will add all values to the arraylist
then loop for each item in the array list and use the registerstartupscript function don't use response.write
you will use 
Page.RegisterStartUpScript("key"+i, "window.open(...)",true)

Answer (score 1):

If there is a session variable with the same key value it is overwritten. So you always update the same key with the newest value.

Comment: Right but Im calling the new page each time and it doesnt open the new page until the loop is finished. Thats why the session variables get overwritten:  Response.Write(string.Format("<script>window.open('{0}','_blank');</script>", "Trace" + index + ".aspx"));

Answer (score 1):

You should put a list of ImageIds in session rather than individual images since you can only have one object represented by the same key. It basically gets overwritten every time through your loop.

Comment: How can I execute the opening of a new browser first and then loop through the rest of code?